# How to exclude logo's and icon in Google Search Queries?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm using Google Wemaster Tool. I'm struggle having this unwanted search queries.

```
Japanese           English
電話 アイコン         Phone icon
電話 アイコン png     Phone icon png
電話PNG             Telephone PNG
アイコン 電話         Icon Phone
問い合わせ アイコン    Contact icon
Chinese
電話                Phone
电话                Phone

Arabi
هاتف png            Png phone
Macedonian
виза и мастеркард   Visa and MasterCard logo
```

[image]

What should I do to remove this keywords in my google search queries?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, could you reword your question to explain your problem better?

Comment: Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Jows, don't apologize, your English is fine. It's your problem that is a bit unusual - organic traffic is free after all, so why do you want to remove it, even if the keywords are not particularly relevant ?

Comment: I want to know why the website is showing up for those search terms. Where on their site do they have those search terms that they are showing up for?
And they shouldn't be on the site, because the website does not have a japanese.

Comment: If you have a search box (input field) on your site, visitors can enter anything they want...though it is possible you may have other tracking on your site that is not implemented properly

Comment: I don't have search box in my website.

Answer (score 0):

Provide good context for the image.

After adding alt text and title in the image, the unwanted search queries are gone.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en